# GROUP BY created field in LOAD statement

Tags: qlikview

i'm trying to GROUP by a created field in LOAD statement.

### Here's my script:

```
LOAD 
"EFF_DATE",
 Dual(Month(EFF_DATE) & '-' & Date(EFF_DATE, 'YY'), Num(Year(EFF_DATE)) & Num(Month(EFF_DATE), '00')) AS MonthYear,
 Max("EFF_DATE");

SELECT "EFF_DATE"
FROM "DataSet"
GROUP BY "MonthYear";
```

---

I'm getting the following error:
General error;260 invalid column name: MonthYear: line 4 col 10

I'm trying to find the Max EFF DATE in each MonthYear grouping.

Please assist.

Comment: remove the quote in group by clause

Comment: what RDBMS is this?

Comment: It's not, it's qlikview.  I'm going to remove the sql tag.

Comment: I removed it, but it's still give me me the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are trying to find the end date of each month with the max(EFF_DATE) expression. If not tell me what you are trying to do and I'll edit my answer

Try this

```
SOURCE_DATES:
SELECT "EFF_DATE"
FROM "DataSet";

DATES:
LOAD 
    "EFF_DATE",
    Dual(Month(EFF_DATE) & '-' & Date(EFF_DATE, 'YY'), Num(Year(EFF_DATE)) & Num(Month(EFF_DATE), '00')) AS MonthYear,
monthend("EFF_DATE") as MaxDate
resident SOURCE_DATES;
drop table SOURCE_DATES;
```

What you are trying to do is pass the group by to the SELECT  before it has been created.

Even though the preceding load is typed in before the select it is only executed after the entire result set has been returned. You will require some other method to perform that group by at that step if it is needed in that step.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I understand the error now. 

The monthend expression unfortunately doesn't work for my case, as I need the month end for business days (excluding weekends)

A colleague was able to solve this issue by joining to a calendar in our database. 

Thank you for the help.